# J言語の標準入力が分かりません。1!:1 3で|rank error | 1 !:1 3となります。

Tags: macos

競技プログラミングの問題をJ言語で解いてみようと、J言語について調べています。

先ずは、標準入力を標準出力に出したいと思い、標準入力を探しました。

[Read input from line in J - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693806/read-input-from-line-in-j/13694424#13694424)
"
That's a common mistake with foreigns.

The definition for foreign 1!:1 doesn't help, because it really reads:

1!:1 y      Read. y is a file name or a file number (produced by 1!:21); the 
result is a string of the file contents., e.g. 1!:1 <'abc.q'. The following 
values for y are also permitted:

1 read from the keyboard (does not work within a script)
3 read from standard input (stdin) 
And so replacing y with 3 should work, right? Well, not quite, because what you're really giving as an argument in writing:

1!:1 3"

http://localhost:65001/jijx
で、
1!:1 3
を実行したところ、

> >
>   |rank error
>   |   1    !:1 3

と、ランクエラーが出ました。

環境は、MacOSで、

```
brew install cask j
```

でJ言語をインストールしました。

青いアプリの

> > jhs901.app

で立ち上げたJ HTTP SERVER
のIDE(?)を使ってます。

よろしくお願いします。

参考
- [1!: Files](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx001.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J言語というのは懐かしのAPLの後継となるべく設計された言語ということで、興味深かったので、ニワカではありますが調べさせてもらいました。

まず、ランクエラーのランク(rank)と言う言葉ですが、これは一般的な他言語で言う所の多次元配列の次元数(場合によっては、各次元の要素数を表すかもしれない)を表します。

[`!:`と言うconjunction(接続詞)](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/xmain.htm)は、

> The conjunction !: applies to integer scalar left and right arguments to produce verbs

(拙訳)

> `!:`と言う接続詞は、左右両辺の整数型スカラーに適用されて、動詞を生成します

と書かれています。つまり`!:`の左右両辺は整数型スカラー(言わば0次元配列)でないといけないのです。

ところが、あなたの入力、

```
1 !:1 3
```

では、`!:`の右辺に`1 3`と言う1次元配列を与えています。

よって、「次元数が合わないよ」と言うエラーになっているのです。

---

対処方法は、リンク先の回答に書かれているのですが、その前半部分は、「[(あなたも挙げられた)ドキュメント](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx001.htm)は、見にくいよね、ドキュメントの`y`を置き換えるだけじゃ使えないんだよ」と言うことの説明になっています。

と言うわけで、最後の1行だけを見てください。

> ```
> 1!:1]3
> ```

他の言語の文法に慣れている人には`]`が単独で使われているのには違和感があるかもしれませんが、常に右方優先で式を解釈するJ言語ではこれで「`!:`の右辺は`1`だけ」を示すのに十分なわけです。

---

[動作確認は公式サイトからダウンロード](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Installation/J901/Zips)したjconsoleで行ったので、若干標準入力の取り扱いが異なるかもしれませんが、少なくともrank errorは出なくなるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！僕も
brew cask install j
でインストールした、jc901.appでターミナルを開き打ち込んだら、
エラーは出ませんでした。標準入力で受けとったものを標準出力するには、
```
echo 1!1]3
```
ですか？これは、また別の質問を立てるべきでしょうか？

Comment: @user9501997 さん、その通りですね。とりあえずjconsoleでは、それで標準出力に出力できました。ただ、jconsoleでは、1行入力した後にCtrl-Dを打たないと入力完了と判断されなかったので、1行分入力して処理を続ける、と言うのはこれではできないようですね。

Comment: OOPerさん。ありがとうございます。Ctrl-Dを打たないと入力完了とならないのが、ネックですね。調べてみます。

Comment: @DrqYuto さん、その辺はJ言語が選べる競技プログラミングではどのように解決するものかわかりませんが、もともと`1!:1`はファイル全体を読み込むと言う動作をするものみたいなので、標準入力をコンソールに繋いだ時にはCtrl-Dを打つまで、と言うのは正しい動作ではあるのですが。良い方法を見つけられたら、何らかの形で情報をシェアしてくださると助かります。

Comment: Twitterでみたら、CodeGolfをするサイトでJ言語を使っている方がいたので、そのサイトを見てみます！ファイル全体読み込みだったんですね。